# Interactively show/hide plots in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot, interaction

(just documenting - self-answer to follow)

In `gnuplot`, I can have two plots (say, `sin(x)` and `cos(x)` like this:

```
gnuplot> plot sin(x), cos(x)
```

which provides a graph like this:

[image: gnuplot window]

I'd like to interactively click on something, and (say) hide `sin(x)` - then again click somewhere with the mouse to show it.

I've seen (in http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_canvas_4.6/) that it is possible to do that with a HTML5 `canvas` terminal - in my Firefox, I can click on the small circled `1` in the demo, to show/hide one of the plots there. Unfortunately, it seems that the `canvas` terminal is only available for `gnuplot` 4.6 - while I'm using 4.4.

Is there a similar sort of facility for the interactive terminals in earlier versions of `gnuplot`?

Comment: As written in the answer by @sdaau, you just click on the legend entry, No need to select the ```wxt`` terminal, at least on Linux.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, it turns out there is - I just couldn't find anything in the documentation.

First you need to click on the wrench icon ("Open configuration dialog") on the `wxt` terminal window; in there, there is an option "Toggle plots on/off when key sample is clicked", which should be enabled.

If it is, then one can simply click on the function entry *in the legend* (that is, the key), and the visibility of that particular plot will be toggled there.

NB: The phrase "key sample" confused me, because if you plot data of, say, 2 points (say, (0,0) and (1,1)) with, say, `linespoints`, then you'd get "points" at (0,0) and (1,1), and a line that connects them; usually I would have considered the "points" to be "key samples" (in analogy to "key frames"), whereas the line would represent "interpolated samples" - but that is not the meaning here; here clicking on "key sample" means clicking on the entry in the legend!

Hope this helps someone,
Cheers!

Comment: Where is the wrench icon?  What is a `wxt` window?

Comment: The wrench icon is on the window gnuplot creates. Not sure what wxt is, probably another name for the window gnuplot creates: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node441.html

Comment: @wallyk: ```wxt``` is one of the (many) terminals available to gnuplot. Yoi select it by giving the command ```set terminal wxt```. However, while working on Linux, I see that the default terminal behaves the same: when you click on the legend entry for a given plot, you toggle the appearance of that plot